# probability? Marbles question

Tags: probability, probability-theory

A bag contains two blue marbles and two red ones; two marbles are drawn at random.

(a) What is wrong with the following argument?
Because there are four possibilities – (red, red), (blue, blue), (red, blue), (blue, red) – the probability
that both are red is 0.25.

(b) Find the correct probability that both marbles are red.

Comment: what did you try?

Comment: The argument would work if the first marble taken was put back in the bag before the second one was taken.

Answer (score 2):

1. **Hint:** why should each event happen with the same probability?
2. The probability that the first one is red is $1/2$; then the probability to get the second one is $1/3$. The whole probability is then $1/6$.

Here I implicitly used the formula
$$
P(1=R, 2=R) = P(1=R)P(2=R|1=R)
$$

Another way to get the answer:
there are $\binom 42 =6$ possibilities, with $\binom 22=1$ favorable cases.

Answer (score 1):

You can't just look at possible macrostate outcomes, you have to consider their microstates.

While your red marbles look the same, they are actually distinct, as are the two blue.

Your bag really contains $\{\color{red}{r_1}, \color{red}{r_2}, \color{blue}{b_1}, \color{blue}{b_2}\}$ so your possible pairs are actually:

$$(\color{red}{r_1}, \color{red}{r_2}), (\color{red}{r_2}, \color{red}{r_1}), \\ (\color{red}{r_1}, \color{blue}{b_1}), (\color{red}{r_1}, \color{blue}{b_2}), (\color{red}{r_2}, \color{blue}{b_1}), (\color{red}{r_2}, \color{blue}{b_2}), \\ (\color{blue}{b_1}, \color{red}{r_1}), (\color{blue}{b_1}, \color{red}{r_2}), (\color{blue}{b_2}, \color{red}{r_2}), (\color{blue}{b_2}, \color{red}{r_2}),\\ (\color{blue}{b_1}, \color{blue}{b_2}), (\color{blue}{b_2}, \color{blue}{b_1})$$

So while $(\color{red}{red}, \color{red}{red})$ is one of the four macrostates, it is actually just 2 of the 24 equally-possible microstates.  $\mathcal{Pr}((\color{red}{red}, \color{red}{red}))=\frac 1 6$

---

Alternatively: look at the probability of drawing one red marble from all four and then, given that, the probability of drawing a second red marble from the three remaining.  Put them together.

$\mathcal{Pr}((\color{red}{red}, \color{red}{red})) = \mathcal{Pr}((\color{red}{red}, ?)\cdot \mathcal{Pr}((?, \color{red}{red})\mid (\color{red}{red}, ?)) = \frac 2 4 \cdot \frac 1 3 = \frac 1 6$

Answer (score 0):

The probability of getting either color the first time is $\frac{1}{2}$. When you take out the second ball there is only $3$ balls left so, the probability of it being the same color is not $\frac{1}{4}$ but $\frac{1}{3}$. $\frac{1}{2} \times \frac{1}{3} = \frac{1}{6}$.

http://teachers.greenville.k12.sc.us/sites/jbryant/math/Shared%20Documents/MATH_logo.PNG